# How to get rolling subset from postgresql into pandas data frame

Tags: postgresql, pandas, loops, dynamic, sqlalchemy

I have a postgresql database from which I query a subset and write it to a pandas data frame.

```
# Set parameters
train_win = 10

stmt_stream = ("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime)" 
                    "AS row_n, * FROM table_test) as query 
                    WHERE query.row_n >= 1 AND 
                    query.row_n < 1 + train_win 
                    ORDER BY query.row_n;")
df = pd.read_sql(stmt_stream, eng)

# only needed here to intermediate results
df.head(n=len(df))

df.drop(['row_n', 'year', 'date', 'itime'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

df.set_index(['datetime'])

# Next do some analysis with the 10 data rows.
```

After the analysis is done with the first data set, I would like to "loop" back again and retrieve another subset - range dependent on i.

Could you please advice I tried to do:

```
# Set parameters
train_win = 10

for i in range(3):
    stmt_stream = ("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime)" 
                    "AS row_n, * FROM table_test) as query WHERE query.row_n >= "
                    + str(i + 1) + " AND query.row_n < " + str(i + 1 + train_win) + 
                    " ORDER BY query.row_n;")
df = pd.read_sql(stmt_stream, eng)

...
```

but it seems that my first 2 data subsets are immediately overwritten before I can run any analysis on them.

Comment: In your first query you're not actually passing `train_win` as parameter. In the second part you're passing arguments to a query using string formatting (concatenating), which is wrong and dangerous. Use placeholders instead. The reason the first 2 are discarded is that in the loop you simply reassign `stmt_stream` over and over. The call to `read_sql` is not a part of the loop.

Comment: Thank you Ilja. How would you suggest to make the 'SELECT' statement dynamic, doesn't it need to be a string? Actually, my idea was that stmt_stream gets passed to df, and immediately gets "deleted" to save resources.

Comment: Make it dynamic by using placeholders and passing the arguments/params to `read_sql()` separately. Read the relevant documentation for how. You don't save much resources by "immediately" deleting a string, which `stmt_stream` is. And still, are you planning on storing the 3 query result sets and performing analysis on them, or performing analysis on them separately in a loop? In both cases see the previous comment: you have to move the actual reading to the loop, but whether or not you then store all 3 sets or not may differ.

Comment: thanks Ilja, the process should be as follows: pull 1 data set, perform analysis, (delete the data set), pull data set 2, perform analysis etc. and data sets differ just by the different windows